# Update state value in deep nested .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**The state** 
`const [config, setConfig] = useContext(ConfigContext)`

**The .map on the config state**

```
                {config[categoryNumber]?.config?.map((x: ConfigParam, i: number) =>
                                <tr key={i}>
                                    <td>{x?.desc}</td>
                                    <Switch
                                        checked={x.value}
                                        onChange={handleChange()}
                                    />
                                    <td>{x?.unit}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )}
```

**handleChange() function**

```
    const handleChange = () => {
    /* 
      The desire is that this function will update the value of the original array(the config state) 
       What is the best practice for achieving this behavior? 
    */
    }
```

**The config state object** 
[image: The config state object]

Any alternative suggestions for a solution is

Comment: What kind of update are you trying to achieve? Do you need to clone and update or just remove and update? Please be more specific

Comment: Just updating the current value to anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on your code. To store state you should use.

**useState** instead of **useContext**, **useContext** it is *mostly* to avoid prop drilling.

So your code should be:

```
const [config, setConfig] = useState(ConfigContext)

handleChange(){

setConfig(prevConfigContext=> ({...prevConfigContext, children: 'Changed'})

}
```

In case you are wondering what **useContext** would do.

Please read:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

In short this function (hook) exposes the value of previous Context.Provider up in the tree and there is no *set* function in it. It is used for **reading**